# I am facing folder permission in my xampp server

Tags: php, passport.js, laravel-5.4

I am facing folder permission problem in my  xampp server. when i am running laravel command php artisan route:list. then i am getting error

```
[ErrorException]
 Key file "file://G:\Local Server\xampp\htdocs\Examples\example 
 1\laravel\storage\oauth-private.key" permissions are not correct, should be 
 600 or 660 instead of 666.
```

Comment: Why not do exactly what it says? Set the perms to 600 or 660 instead of 666? It's pretty rare to get an error that tells you exactly how to solve it, so when you do, it should be pretty easy to fix.

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/windows-vista/taking-ownership-file-or-folder-command-line